# No audio from mobo after new GPU

Tags: nvidia, sound, alsa

I've searched extensively through existing resources, many of them have every single symptom presented by my system, but their solutions are not working for me.

This user has had a similar experience: [PulseAudio has no sound, only has Dummy Output](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1359038/pulseaudio-has-no-sound-only-has-dummy-output)

I ran into all of the suggested solutions he also has, and tried them one by one.

Previously I was running an 1660Ti, no problem having both HDMI/DP sound and mobo sound simultaneously. I've since then upgraded to a 3070 and from there I have not had mobo sound.

Finally, I tried the answer suggested on the linked question - https://askubuntu.com/a/1359089 - it does correctly set my mobo card as default, however it just shows as Dummy Output.

I have made sure I have all the required modules in my kernel as suggested here: [Only "Dummy output" (sound) in Ubuntu 20.04 after reboot - Broken driver / module](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1258510/only-dummy-output-sound-in-ubuntu-20-04-after-reboot-broken-driver-modul)

I've also tried downgrading to a previous kernel version.

Although I didn´t fiddle with them, I tried loading live versions of Ubuntu and Fedora, but both had the same problem.

```
  ~ ❯ aplay -l                                                  at  19:50:20
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [2460G4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [PGCTRBL01]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 0: ALC892 Analog [ALC892 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Output from alsa-info.sh: http://alsa-project.org/db/?f=db17d1766d174aa2949d96221be9143bcc65e3a5

One thing to note, I'm running Pop!_OS 22.04 but I'm posting here given the lack of a good Pop!_OS community for support.

Comment: I plugged back the 1660ti and still no sound. Could my sound card have fried at some point when switching GPUs?

Answer (score 0):

Your headphones are probably on mute, that is why they are not showing

you can try going on alsamixer and unmuting

Comment: hi. I had gone through this before, seems that every now and then it resets to mute, but still no changes when unmuting and rebooting